# Je viens de + verbe

Tags: sens

Je me demande, le sens de la phrase :

> je viens de `corriger` quelque chose.

Ça signifie que je suis dans quelle phase d'avancement; La fin ? Le début ? Ou au milieu ?

Toute réponse avec exemples sera vraiment appréciée.

Comment: Pardon mais ta phrase n'est pas claire. Indique juste la phrase qui te pose problème entre guillemets, s'il-te-plait.

Comment: C bon et merci pour votre retour

Comment: [Lien comlémentaire](https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/les-temps/le-passe-recent)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La formule « venir de + *verbe* » affirme qu'une action s'est très récemment achevée. Elle signifie que cette action est celle que tu as terminée tout à l'heure, juste avant le moment de référence.

> *Tu révises le code d'un collègue. Soudain, tu t'aperçois d'une erreur et tu la corriges. Tout de suite, ce collègue s'approche de toi.*
>
> **Collègue :** T'as trouvé quelque chose ?
>
> **Toi :** Oui, je viens de corriger une erreur. Mais le reste semble être parfait.

Je dis « avant le moment de référence » et non « avant le moment où tu parles » parce que tu peux employer cette formule au passé :

> **Ami :** Désolé d'avoir manqué ton appel hier soir. Qu'est-ce que tu voulais ?
>
> **Toi :** Bon, je venais d'apprendre qu'on me demandait de déménager en Californie, et je voulais te demander ton avis !

Note que « venir de » peut s'employer même si des actions peu importantes interviennent : l'action s'est produite récemment, mais comme elle ne se produit que peu fréquemment, elle reste très présente dans ta mémoire.

> T'as reçu un appel de ce maudit télévendeur de nettoyage de conduits ? Nous aussi on vient de les entendre, c'était samedi pendant le souper ...

Comment: Merci pour les corrections !

Answer (score 3):

"Venir de" en tant qu'auxiliaire indique que l'action s'est achevée dans un passé très proche.

Pour des actions proches du présent, le français utilise une série de constructions périphrastiques pour indiquer l'aspect:

- Je suis sur le point de corriger les copies (L'action n'a pas encore commencé, mais va l'être dans un futur très proche
- Je me suis mis à corriger les copies (aspect inchoatif, l'action vient de commencer)
- Je suis en train de corriger les copies (aspect duratif ou progressif, l'action est en cours)
- Je viens de corriger les copies (aspect parfait+passé proche, l'action s'est terminée dans un passé immédiat)

Il y a d'autre façons plus explicites pour exprimer ces sens (par example, "j'ai commencé à corriger les copies") mais ces dernières devraient poser moins de problèmes de compréhension ou d'interprétation.

Comment: Franchement merci beaucoup ca m'a éclairer la vision...Vous etes vraiment fort